# Scraping each td element with a specific attribute

Tags: node.js, cheerio

I'm trying to scrape the elements from [this](https://inducks.org/issue.php?c=it%2FTL++300) page using node and cheerio js. I want to get all the stuff inside each row that has the first "td" with background color as #cbdced.

So the request would be: "for each tr, if the first td has the attribute of bgcolor #cbdced, scrape the elements inside all the tds in that row". How can i translate it to cheerio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const url = 'https://inducks.org/issue.php?c=it%2FTL++300';

async function scrape() {
  let response;
  try {
    response = await axios.get(url);
  }
  catch (ex) {
    console.log('Exception:', ex);
    return;
  }

  const html = response.data;
  const $ = cheerio.load(html);
  const matchingTableDatas = $('tr > td:first-child[bgcolor="#cbdced"]');

  for (let i = 0; i < matchingTableDatas.length; i++) {
    const parentTableRowNode = matchingTableDatas[i].parentNode;
    parentTableRowNode.children.forEach((child) => {
      console.log($(child).html());
    })
  }
}

scrape();
```